# How do you set and check a single bit in a programming language that does not support bitwise operations?

Tags: operators, binary, bitwise-operators

I'm using a programming language (more a scripting language) that does not support any bitwise operators like AND, OR, XOR, NOT (and shift as well).

Common arithmetic and logical operations like + - * / % > >= < <= == !=, logical AND, OR, NOT and control flow (while, for, if,...) are supported however. It is like a "subset of C", but without these binary operators. My question does not target that particular language anyway.

I was wondering if there is any (mathematical ?) way to set and check a bit at a specific position in a programming language that does not support bitwise operations :

```
a = 0;               //00000000b
a = togglebit(a, 5); //00100000b
a = togglebit(a, 2); //00100100b


a = 0xFE;            //11111110b
bool result = checkbit(a, 4); //true
```

For example, there is a way to perform a left or right binary shift using integer multiplication or division :

```
a = a * 2; //similar to left  shift : a = a << 1;
a = a / 2; //similar to right shift : a = a >> 1;
```

I'm looking for something similar but for setting or checking a flag.

Comment: The Wikipedia article on bitwise operations explains the [mathematical equivalents](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#Mathematical_equivalents), mostly they seem to be based on some modulo2 operations.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To check the *n* th bit, shift right *n* times. If the bit is set, the result will be odd (numbers are odd if and only if their final bit is 1.)

```
function checkbit(a, n)
  n times:
    a = a / 2   (integer division)
  return a % 2
end
```

To set the *n* th bit, add 2^*n* only if the bit is not yet set.

```
function pow2(n):   (returns 2^n)
  result = 1
  n times: result = result * 2
  return result
end

function setbit(a, n)
  if checkbit(a, n):
    return a
  else:
    return a + pow2(n)
end
```

Toggling it is similar, but we subtract if the bit is already set:

```
function togglebit(a, n)
  if checkbit(a, n):
    return a - pow2(n)
  else:
    return a + pow2(n)
end
```

Bitwise negation depends on how big your bitmasks are; specifically, the bitwise negative of an *n*-bit bitmask *a* is *2^n-1-a*. If you're using 16 bits, it would be *65535-a*.